# how jquery .remove() function works?

Tags: jquery

I have experienced the JQuery remove function in my developments, when i run the code, the removed item is still available on the source code. But it is not appearing at the inspect elements window. how is it possible?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: some code would be nice

Comment: Show us your code, what actually you tried? or make an online demo of it. Also change the title to `jquery .remove() function is not working` instead of `how jquery .remove() function works?` which contradicts your problem

Comment: "still available on the source code" Sure because source code is not updated when you change anything in the DOM. Source code is the source of the page. This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: ^^^ What he said, anytime you're viewing the source, you're not really viewing an accurate representation of the DOM, but the source code before anything changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

`remove()` simply removes the jQuery collection from the DOM. It will not unset your variables or indeed remove the elements from the jQuery collection.

Answer (score 1):

For example;

```
<div id="example" name="example">
    <p>
    Hello there!
    </p>
</div>
```

If you call

```
$("#example").children().remove();
```

That removes p tags;

```
<div id="example" name="example">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

More over, you can add removed DOM node stored in your variable back to DOM structure - this is why your variable still accessible.